# How to Hide black screen while executing Executable file which we have generated through pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have created a Executable file through pyinstaller. To generate Executable file I am using below command in virtual environment:

```
pyinstaller --onefile imp.py
```

**Note:** the Executable file contains Tkinter code

Once I click on the file to execute it, It popup with 2 screen, one is Black Screen and Other is Tkinter Screen (Refer below Image for the same)

Output for Executing `imp.exe` file as below Image:

[image]

**Question:**
How can I hide the black screen which you can see in above Image? (It should not be visible when I execute the Executable file, I want to showcase only tkinter Window)

Thanks for replies. It will be very helpful for me if someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `--noconsole` flag to your pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole imp.py
```

This will make so that the black terminal window will never appear.

Comment: When I am adding --windowed then Tkinter window is also not appearing with black terminal